# Why does Git generate a random SHA?

Tags: git, version-control, sha

If the SHA were generated by the data in the commit, then Git would know when two commits are the same.

This would solve problems when rebasing and generating commits that are really the same but Git thinks that they are different because they have different SHA's.

Is this logic correct or am I missing something?

Comment: SHA is by definition not random. It's a deterministic function of its input. If it's different, that means the input was different, too.

Comment: The data in the commit is used to generate the SHA of the tree.  If you use `git cat-file -p sha` on the sha of the commit, you will see the sha of the tree, which is determined solely by the content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The SHA of a commit includes the parent SHA commit. That's why it changes when rebasing even if the commit itself doesn't change - it's parent changes (because that the whole point of a rebase).

Answer (score 5):

If they were really the same commit, they would have the same random SHA.

Assuming your assertion that a random SHA is used is correct... If the commits are identical in terms of the diffs, they are still different because of time, who made them, and to which previous commit the diffs were applied. etc.

Comment: When rebasing the time, author and committer don't change. Only the parent commit changes.